# Is there an official torrent for elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation, files, download

I'm adding all of the operating systems I've tried's torrents to a folder in Google Drive so I can download/install them anywhere/anytime without the bulk of the .iso file.

I looked on the website and only saw the magnet link and the .iso file but I would really like an up-to-date torrent file.

Comment: Copy the magnet link and paste that link in the form on [`http://magnet2torrent.me/`](http://magnet2torrent.me/). If the magnet is still active that web page will get the `.torrent` file and allow you to download it.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver That's perfect! Thank you! I have the website bookmarked so I can do it with other stuff too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always generate a torrent file from the magnet link in case you need it. Just do the following:

1. Open the magnet link using your torrent client
2. Wait until metadata has been downloaded from peers (your torrent will now then start downloading the actual files, you can pause the download on this stage)
3. This varies from the torrent client you're using. Find the menubar item or right-click context menu that says something like "Save torrent file As..." and select it.
4. You will now be presented to save the `.torrent` file on your desired location

AFAIK there's also some programs or web apps that does this for you automatically. In case you don't trust such third-party services and you want maximum compatibility with your torrent client, I suggest doing the steps above instead.